# Storm bolt instances communication

Tags: java, apache-storm

AFAIK storm spout/bolt instances runs independently without any communication.

For example consider the storm wordcount topology

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/WordCountTopology.java

```
builder.setBolt("split", new SplitSentence(), 8).shuffleGrouping("spout");
builder.setBolt("count", new WordCount(), 12).fieldsGrouping("split", new Fields("word"));
```

It defines a topology with 2 bolts.

SplitSentence bolt having 8 instances and WordCount bolt having 12 instances running in parallel.

Is there any communication among these bolts instances?

If my requirement is to produce only relative word count then it should check the current word count with the previous timestamp and word count and update the current timestamp and count as old timestamp and count.

How to make sure the old data (same data - synchronized) is available to all the bolt instances?

Eg:
Normal word count example (Streaming):

> Time--------------Sentence-------------word count
>
> 10:00 AM -> Hello world Hello  ->   Hello 2, world 1
>
> 10:15 AM -> Hello world Hello  another world -> Hello 2, world 2, another 1

Relative word count:

> Time--------------Sentence-------------word count
>
> 10:00 AM -> Hello world Hello  ->   Hello 2, world 1
>
> 10:15 AM -> Hello world Hello  another world -> world 1, another 1

It should get the difference from previous word count.

=====================================

Does Storm provides any synchronization or communication between bolt instances?

Or do we need to use Zookeeper for data synchronization?

Or else any another better approach?

Comment: Well.... your requirement is not clear from the question. Yes Storm uses Zookeeper.... but only for cluster management... not for message passing. Can you better explain your question ?

Comment: please read :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249388/distributed-caching-in-storm/28260813#28260813

Comment: Got the answer from below SO question

[stackoverflow.com/questions/28249388/distributed-caching-in-storm/28260813][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249388/distributed-caching-in-storm/28260813