# Spark streaming data sharing between batches

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Spark streaming processes the data in micro batches.

Each interval data is processed in parallel using RDDs with out any data sharing between each interval.

But my use case needs to share the data between intervals.

Consider the [Network WordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaNetworkWordCount.java) example which produces the count of all words received in that interval.

How would I produce following word count ?

- Relative count for the words "hadoop" and "spark" with the previous interval count
- Normal word count for all other words.

Note: UpdateStateByKey does the Stateful processing but this applies function on every record instead of particular records.

So, UpdateStateByKey doesn't fit for this requirement.

Update:

consider the following example

**Interval-1**

**Input:**

```
Sample Input with Hadoop and Spark on Hadoop
```

**output:**

```
hadoop  2
sample  1
input   1
with    1
and 1
spark   1
on  1
```

**Interval-2**

**Input:**

```
Another Sample Input with Hadoop and Spark on Hadoop and another hadoop another spark spark
```

**output:**

```
another 3
hadoop  1
spark   2
and 2
sample  1
input   1
with    1
on  1
```

**Explanation:**

1st interval gives the normal word count of all words.

In the 2nd interval hadoop occurred 3 times but the output should be 1 (3-2)

Spark occurred 3 times but the output should be 2 (3-1)

For all other words it should give the normal word count.

So, while processing 2nd Interval data, it should have the 1st interval's word count of **hadoop** and **spark**

This is a simple example with illustration.

In actual use case, fields that need data sharing are part of the RDD element(RDD) and huge no of values needs to be tracked.

i.e, in this example like hadoop and spark keywords nearly 100k keywords to be tracked.

**Similar usecases in Apache Storm:**

[Distributed caching in storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249388/distributed-caching-in-storm/28260813#28260813)

[Storm TransactionalWords](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/TransactionalWords.java)

Comment: Please clarify 'Relative count for the words "hadoop" and "spark" with the previous interval count'. Don't hesitate to formalise your definition introducing variables and a formula. You can also give an example.

Comment: Filter out the unwanted ones and updateStateByKey?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible by "remembering" the last RDD received and using a left join to merge that data with the next streaming batch. We make use of `streamingContext.remember` to enable RDDs produced by the streaming process to be kept for the time we need them.

We make use of the fact that `dstream.transform` is an operation that executes on the driver and therefore we have access to all local object definitions. In particular we want to update the mutable reference to the last RDD with the required value on each batch.

Probably a piece of code makes that idea more clear:

```scala
// configure the streaming context to remember the RDDs produced
// choose at least 2x the time of the streaming interval
ssc.remember(xx Seconds)  

// Initialize the "currentData" with an empty RDD of the expected type
var currentData: RDD[(String, Int)] = sparkContext.emptyRDD

// classic word count
val w1dstream = dstream.map(elem => (elem,1))    
val count = w1dstream.reduceByKey(_ + _)    

// Here's the key to make this work. Look how we update the value of the last RDD after using it. 
val diffCount = count.transform{ rdd => 
                val interestingKeys = Set("hadoop", "spark")               
                val interesting = rdd.filter{case (k,v) => interestingKeys(k)}                                
                val countDiff = rdd.leftOuterJoin(currentData).map{case (k,(v1,v2)) => (k,v1-v2.getOrElse(0))}
                currentData = interesting
                countDiff                
               }

diffCount.print()
```

Comment: streamingContext.remember - remember RDDs it generated in the last given duration (may be cache/ persist). There are many RDD transformations and actions associated with this streamingContext. So, lot of RDDs needs to remembered..

Comment: I am interested to know more on the fact that dstream.transform is an operation that executes on the driver. Could you please post any references..

Comment: I think leftOuterJoin will be costly operation when the data size is huge. i.e, rdd if of 10 lakh records and currentData is of 1 lakh records which are distributed in a cluster.

Comment: @VijayInnamuri  There's another version I thought of using `filter` + `union` that could be probably more efficient than the l-join. The l-join is more elegant, but indeed might come with a cost. The overall concept is similar: use `dstream.transform` to deal with RDD operations. I think you'll have to compare some options before deciding on a final impl.

Comment: @VijayInnamuri for transform, look at the dedicated paragraph on doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams