# Distributed data visiting in Storm cluster and how does MemoryMapState store distributed data?

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-storm

I'm trying to develop a topology which could have some so-called "global variables", just like what question [Distributed caching in storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249388/distributed-caching-in-storm) did. I know it's better to use some kind of distributed cache store, like Memcache or Redis, but I still have a few questions:

1. How to visit caching data more efficiently? Seems it's not a good idea to visit caching in `execute` or `nextTuple` function directly, should I create a thread in spout/bolt to get those data periodically?
2. `MemoryMapState` is a "state" used to store persistent result in storm trident. It's said that `MemoryMapState` uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` to store caching data, as codes in `class MemoryMapState` show below

   ```
   static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<List<Object>, Object>> _dbs = 
               new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<List<Object>, Object>>();
   ```

   So, how could a `ConcurrentHashMap` store and query data among different machines in Storm cluster?